# Broken Equation Solver

Tags: python

I'm writing code to solve an equation by brute-forcing. The code will manually substitute `x` into two equations. Then the code finds the difference between both equation's results. After that, it'll increase the value of `x`. The goal is to find a difference that is as near as possible to zero (minimum value).

```
def brtfrc_eqsolvr(min, max, diff):
    result_library = []
    x = min
    while x < max:
        eq1 = 2 * x +3
        eq2 = 5 * x - 1
        result_library.append(abs(eq1 - eq2))
        x += diff
    print(result_library)
    print(min(result_library))
```

But then I got the following message:

```
print(min(result_library))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Although it printed the result library, the minimum value of the result library doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `min` and `max` as the name of a variable because they are also the name of a built-in function. So, the min and max function will be overwritten.

Change them to other name:

```
def brtfrc_eqsolvr(minimum, maximum, diff):
   ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `passing attribute`:

```
def brtfrc_eqsolvr(minm, maxm, diff):
    result_library = []
    x = minm
    while x < maxm:
        eq1 = 2 * x +3
        eq2 = 5 * x - 1
        result_library.append(abs(eq1 - eq2))
        x += diff
    print(result_library)
    print(min(result_library))

brtfrc_eqsolvr(1,10,2)
```